# Minimal area of a surface that splits a cube into two equal-size pieces

Tags: geometry

I had read the following problem and its solution from one source problem which was the following:

You want to cut a unit cube into two pieces each with volume 1/2. What dividing surface, which might be curved, has the smallest surface area?

The author gave his first solution by this way:
When bisecting the equilateral triangle, an arc of a circle centered at a vertex had the shortest path. Similarly for this problem, the octant (one-eighth) of a sphere should be the bisecting surface with the lowest area. If the cube is a unit cube, then the octant has volume 1/2, so its radius is given by

$$\frac{1}{8}(\frac{4}{3} \pi r^3)=\frac{1}{2}$$

So the radius is $\displaystyle \left( \frac{3}{\pi} \right)^{\frac{1}{3}}$ and the surface area of the octant is

$$\text{surface area}=\frac{4 \pi r^2}{8}=1.52$$ (approximate)

But after this the author said that he made a mistake; the answer was wrong and the correct  one is the simplest surface – a horizontal plane through the center of the cube – which has surface area 1, which is less than the surface area of the octant. But he has not given reasons why the horizontal surface area is the best solution and I need a formula or proof of this. Can you help me?

Comment: Even when bisecting the unit square, a straight line parallel to one pair of sides (length 1) is shorter than a quarter circle centered at a vertex (length 1.253...).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We know from the [isoperimetric inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoperimetric_inequality#Isoperimetric_inequality_in_higher_dimensions) that locally the surface must be a sphere (where we can include the plane as the limiting case of a sphere with infinite radius). Also, the surface must be orthogonal to the cube where they meet; if they're not, you can deform the surface locally to reduce its area. A sphere orthogonal to a cube face must have its centre on that face. You can easily show that it can't contain half the volume if it intersects only one or two faces. Thus, it must either intersect at least three adjacent faces, in which case its centre has to be at the vertex where they meet, or it has to intersect at least two opposite faces, in which case it has to be a plane.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand the first sentence. What do you mean by "locally the surface must be a sphere" and how does that follow from the isoperimetric inequality?

Comment: This argument is beyond me. First you say that it must be a sphere "locally" and then you go ahead and consider all spheres cutting the cube in two equal parts intersecting the cube's surface orthogonally. That the plane then gives the minimal area among those is clear but I simply can't follow your reduction step.

Comment: @Theo: You're aiming at a slightly higher level of rigour than I was aiming at :-) Perhaps I should have said "we know from the proof of the isoperimetric inequality" or even just "we know because balloons are spherical". By "locally a sphere", I meant that any section of it must coincide with a section of a sphere; basically that it *is* a sphere, just not globally since it ends where the cube ends. (This is in response to your first comment; I just read your second comment now.)

Comment: Okay, thanks for the explanation. Yes, I agree with what you outline in your comment (that's what I thought one should do), but I was of the impression that I missed something obvious.

Comment: @Theo: Sorry about that. I had understood the question to be mainly looking for "reasons" for reducing the complexity of searching through all the possible surfaces, and felt that optimal surfaces being spherical could be taken for granted without rigorous proof. Perhaps it would have been better not to mention the isoperimetric inequality at all; I just felt that the already plausible fact that a sphere has to be optimal locally would become even more plausible by reference to a theorem that it's optimal globally.

Comment: Your point about perpendicular intersection is a good one and answers one quick thought I had.  You could also get volume 1/2 with the bisector of a space diagonal, which is a hexagon:  how do we know that isn't smaller area than the square?

Comment: @Ross: That hexagon has side length $a/\sqrt2$ (where $a$ is the cube's side length), so its area is $3\sqrt3/2(a/\sqrt2)^2=(3\sqrt3/4)a^2\approx1.3a^2$. Nevertheless, I'm wondering whether it's actually a counterexample to my argument. I can't imagine how to transform it continuously to an orthogonal surface without first increasing the area. The problem is that moving the intersection line on one face moves the intersection lines on the adjacent faces in the wrong direction, and changing the surface without changing the intersection lines *increases* its area. Do you see a solution?

Comment: @joriki: If you look at the figure at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hexagon.html drawing the top edge towards the corner nearest you and the the bottom edge toward the far vertex must reduce the area, as you are rounding off acute corners

Comment: @Ross: I thought/hoped so at first, too, but as you're improving the angle on those two edges, you're making it worse on the other four. Effectively you're turning the hexagon around an axis through its two corners at half height, and when you've turned until the top and bottom edges reach the centres of their faces, the other four edges have merged into the cube edge on which the vertices at half height lie; their angles have decreased from $\arccos(1/\sqrt3)\approx55$° to $45$° and the area of the rectangle is $\sqrt2a^2>1.3a^2$. Or am I missing a different way to move the edges?

Comment: I was thinking to let the hexagon bend.  One edge is from (1/2,0,0) to (0,1/2,0).  Fix the line from (17/32,0,1/32) to (0,17/32,1/32) and round off the corner from there to the cube with an arc of a circle, doing the symmetric thing on the opposite edge.  Seems like it must help.

Comment: @Ross: I'm not sure that it does. I assume that by "rounding off the corner from there to the cube" you mean bending the hexagon such that it still has an edge on the same face but slightly further away from the (0,0,0) corner than the original edge from (1/2,0,0) to (0,1/2,0). It seems that this would increase the area for the same reason as my turning above does. But even if it could reduce the area locally, where would it lead? I don't see it moving the solution closer to an orthogonal optimum. The only destination I can make out in that general direction is the $\sqrt2a^2$ rectangle.

Comment: I'm not sure how to get to the square in this approach, it just shows a way to locally improve the hexagon.  It seems this would lead to a wavy hexagon, where alternate edges are pulled toward and away from one of the vertices.  But as you say, these waves cannot be optimal.  My imagination is failing, though.

Comment: @Ross: OK, when I find the time I'll write up a simulation.

Answer (score 0):

Following up the discussion joriki and I had, rounding off the corners where the hexagon meets the edge of the cube does reduce the area.  If we look at the cross section where the hexagon meets the wall it looks like this:

[image: hexagon meeting cube]

$\theta$ is the dihedral angle between the hexagon and the cube.  I imagine rounding off the corner with a small radius R.  The surface area is reduced by $\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}R[\cot \theta-(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta)]$.  The area is increased by some small triangles, but their area is quadratic in $R$, being $R (\sec \theta -1)\sqrt{2}R(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta)\frac{1}{2}$ so for small enough $R$ we have reduced the cut area.  We need to do the mirror image on the other side to maintain the volume, but we win there as well.